# How to seperate clothing from the rest of the model

Tags: animation

Im very new to blender and am wondering whether there are any methods to seperate clothing (hair(particles), boots, gloves) from the rest of the model  as I am going to be animating my character and having him wearing a ghillie suit will make animating difficult.

Comment: Particles can't really be separate unless they are objects, whick you can apply. As for the rest just enter edit mode and press P to separate either one by one as desired or P > Loose Parts to automatically break your object into all separate chunks

Comment: It depends how they are attached. Upload the .blend?

Comment: I havent actually added the ghillie suit,boots,gloves etc. to the character yet. It is simply just a rigged makehuman character at the moment. I had to ask the question like this so that the question wouldn't be taken down for being subjective. I asked because I would like to know in advance. What Daurte Farrajoa Ramos said makes alot of sense and is the path I will go down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two fundamental principles to 3D modeling. One is "don't model what can't be seen"; the other is "any part which needs to move independently of any other part needs to be a separate object  from every other part to which it moves in relation". Following these principles, your character will consist of multiple objects: a head, a separate jaw, likely separate eyes, a cap, a pair of hands, a pair of arms, a pair of feet, a pair of legs, and two or more objects  which, combined, make up the torso.

In fact, you will likely have multiple feet: perhaps a pair of combat boots, a pair of parade dress, and a pair of ghillie boots. You won't usually have bot bare feet and shod feet, because you can't usually see the feet through the shoes.